# Return list of columns via function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function

I'd like a function that returns a text string of comma-separated column headers for a given table name. the code below compiles fine and does not produce any errors, however I can't get it to return anything other than `NULL` for tables that do and do not exist.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.return_column_list(tab_name TEXT)
    RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$
        DECLARE
            one_column record;
            column_list TEXT;
        BEGIN

            FOR one_column IN
                SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
                AND table_name = format('%s', tab_name)
            LOOP
                column_list = column_list || one_column || ',';
            END LOOP;

            column_list = left(column_list,length(column_list) - 1);
            RETURN column_list;

        END;
    $BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

---

**Update:**

finally got it working by changing the `DECLARE` section from

```
DECLARE
    one_column record;
    column_list TEXT;
```

to

```
DECLARE
    one_column record;
    column_list TEXT = '';
```

as per the first example [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/76-Quick-Guide-to-writing-PLPGSQL-Functions-Part-2.html). Spent the whole morning trying to figure this one out, can anyone explain why I have to do this?

Comment: `one_column` is a **record** that contains a single attribute. To get the actual `column_name` value you have to use `one_column.column_name`.

Comment: `column_list TEXT;` initialized `column_list` to `null`. Concatenating values to a `null` value yields `null`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it was the variable initialisation bit that threw me! makes perfect sense once you know - will read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for loop at all. You could simply use [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name, ',')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
 AND  table_name =  'testx';
```

You could use it as subquery in your code.

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XMIAK40348)**

---

Or if you need a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.return_column_list(tab_name TEXT)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',') FROM information_schema.columns
                    WHERE table_schema = 'myschema'
                    AND table_name = format('%s', tab_name));
END;
BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/NHFOR41699)**

---

As for variable initialization. Default value is `NULL` and `NULL` concatenated to column_name is still `NULL`.

```
SELECT NULL || 'a';
-- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question, but that is the initial value:

```
 DECLARE variable_name [ CONSTANT ] datatype [ NOT NULL ] [ { DEFAULT | := } initial_value ]
```

You declare the not null situation basically there, in case your function will return nothing, for example no records. For string (text in your case) it is ''.

If null, you also cannot add to it, for example concatenate with the new values!